# how can I manipulate an nginx variable string

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to manipulate an nginx variable.

I have a variable names $user which contains a UPN like someone@example.com
I want to set another variable, $xuser; to be the $user minus the @domain - ie, someone.

This is done in a location block, so I don't think that I can use map.

I have tried this, but $xuser never seems to get set:

```
if ($user ~* "(?<p>[aa-zZ]+)@example.com")
{
        set $xuser $p;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use map in 'http' block.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

```
map $user $xuser {
  ~^(\w+)@example.com $1;
  default '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to convert that into a named match parameter, otherwise it threw an error regarding $1 being undefined